# How can I download an image from Firebase to Swift and then display it in a UIImageView more quickly?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimage

I am downloading images from Firebase to Swift (most are around 5 MB) and then displaying them in a UIImageView. Each one only appears once, so there is no need to cache them for later viewing. Most of the time, they take a second or two to load. Are there ways of making this time shorter?

My code:

```
Database.database().reference().child("movies").child(movieNumString).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
    let UrlString: String? = ((dictionary["posterPhotoURL"] as? String))
    let Url = URL(string: (UrlString)!)

    self.moviePosterImageView.sd_setImage(with: Url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PImage"), options: [], completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            self.moviePosterImageView.image = image
    })
}
```

Comment: No , only you can optimize image size in server

Comment: @Sh_Khan How can I do that?

Comment: Before uploading them to firebase use any desktop app like photoshop or any other online tool to reduce the size

Comment: @Sh_Khan Is there any way to do it after having uploaded them?

Comment: @BobSamuels I wrote an answer with a couple links however; this question is not really following SO format. If you would do a bit of googling beforehand I'm sure you would come across the links I provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see stack overflow [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future.

Most importantly, you should worry about the data and size of the images, the time that it takes to download them will decrease as you decrease the size. Try to decrease the sizes down to some kb.

In Firebase you can have functions that runs server side and for instance, you can perform resizing on the images. See [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) for all the function examples and for resizing [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/image-sharp) is the example using sharp package.